# Почему не работает глобальный обработчик ошибок в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, исключения

Создал контроллер, который обрабатывает ошибки, после возникновения исключения по http-статуса хочу выдавать кастомную страницу с описанием ошибки:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorsController implements ErrorController {
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound.class)
    public String handleNotFound(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Страница не найдена.");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Страница, которую вы ищете не существует.");
        return "errors/error-custom";
    }
}
```

Пока что сделал только обработку по 404, намеренно ввожу в поисковую строку неверную страницу, но получаю только самое обычное окно. Проверил в дебаге, он даже не заходит на этот метод. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я написал не так и верно ли, что мне нужно будет для каждой ошибки писать метод обработки с почти что одинаковым кодом (если код повторяется, то скорее всего это можно реализовать как-то проще). Эту реализацию написал на основании статьи Spring.io (https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: А вы используете Spring Boot? Или ваше приложение без него?

Comment: Здравствуйте, использую

Comment: Для отладки требуются детали. Уточните, что не работает и в чем ошибка. Приведите [минимальный пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который можно воспроизвести.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

Скорее всего ошибка перехватывается встроенными в Спринг-Бут @ExceptionHandler

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает. Я так понимаю, это костыль, а где и как это лечить правильно?

Comment: Нет, это не костыль, это зависит от того какую ошибку вы хотите перехватить. Это такая особенность работы спринга :)

Comment: То есть поменять это в настройках проекта никак не получится, и этот вариант не считается плохой практикой?

Comment: Да, это абсолютно нормально, я в одном проекте выставлял @Order на десяток ControllerAdvice, потому что они должны были идти в определенном порядке

Comment: Еще раз большое Вам спасибо, Вы очень меня выручили